# How to mount a dual hfs/iso9660 cd as iso9660 in Mac OS Mountail Lion?

Tags: macos, mount, compact-disc

I'm trying to install Warcraft III and run it using Wine.  However it's loading the Mac image off of the CD, and it only has a PowerPC version, which is not supported.

Is there a way to mount the Windows/cd9600 image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 Open terminal

2 List all volumes to determine which volume we need to force mount.

```
$ diskutil list
```

identify the CD mount identifier for the first volume mine was disk1s1. disk0 is normally your internal HD and disk1 is normally the first other drive you have inserted in your system, in this case the CD.

Note if you have other .dmg files mounted or usb drives mounted the CD may be on disk2 or disk3?
Once you determine which disk it is you want to mount the first partition of that disk.

In my case it was disk1s1.

From trial and error I figured it was normally the first s1 after the disk rather than s1s1 or s1s2
this is what you will get once you run $ diskutil list

```
/dev/disk1
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:        CD_partition_scheme                        *790.8 MB   disk1
       1:     Apple_partition_scheme                         658.4 MB   disk1s1
       2:        Apple_partition_map                         1.0 KB     disk1s1s1
       3:                  Apple_HFS Untitled CD             658.0 MB   disk1s1s2
```

Once you know the disk IDENTIFIER as disk1s1 we can force mount it using something called cd9660.fs.

3 we need to make a directory for us to mount the partition into.

```
$ mkdir /Volumes/tempCD
```

4 now we can mount the partition disk1s1 into our newly created tempCD directory

```
$ sudo /System/Library/Filesystems/cd9660.fs/Contents/Resources/cd9660.util -M disk1s1 /Volumes/tempCD
```

sudo means you will have to put the admin password in when you run this command.

You will now get a mounted CD called tempCD and you should be able to browse the files on it.

5 to unmount the CD you will have to run this command

```
$ sudo /System/Library/Filesystems/cd9660.fs/Contents/Resources/cd9660.util -u disk1s1 /Volumes/tempCD
```

*In future you do not need to run the  $ mkdir /Volumes/tempCD as it already exists so you only need to run mount and unmount steps 4 and 5 and of course each time you put in a new disk run step 1 to make sure you are mounting the correct partition of the correct disk.*

Answer (score 0):

- Run `mount` to list the currently mounted disks. Find the one for the disk you are interested in. E.g. `/dev/disk2s1s2`
- Create a new directory under `/Volumes`, e.g. `/Volumes/win`
- Mount to the new directory with `sudo mount_cd9660 -er /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/win`. 9660 is the windows CD format, ISO 9660. Pay close attention to the device name, it is not the same as what is listed for `mount`. There is only one `s`, you truncate the extra `s`. So instead of `/dev/disk2s1s2`, you just use `/dev/disk2s1`.
- Now when you go to `/Volumes/win`, it should have the Windows files, not the Mac files.